# Running anypoint-cli from jenkins pipeline

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins-pipeline, mule, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

i am trying to run anypoint-cli from Jenkins pipeline script for one of my CI-CD application ,
i will exceute the maven package in the project root and perform the deployment of mule project to anypoint cloudhub using anypoint-cli , all these will be done in ubuntu machine , so my command will be like this

```
"anypoint-cli --username=******* --password=****** --organization=**** runtime-mgr cloudhub-application modify --runtime 3.9.1 --workers 1 --workerSize 0.1 --region us-east-1 --property api.name=api.name=groupId:*****:assetId:*** --property api.version=api.version=2.0:***( --property env=DEV anypointproject3 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeployMuleApplication/49/target/banking-account-summary-mdm-api-v1.0.zip"
```

in the terminal when i execute this deployment happens

```
root@:~# anypoint-cli --username=*******--password=***** --organization=*****
runtime-mgr cloudhub-application modify --runtime 3.9.1 --workers 1 --workerSize 0.1 --region us-east-1 --property api.name=api.name=groupId:340065b3-09a3-4a45-9c36-ebcdfae43659:assetId:TransactionAPI --property api.version=api.version=2.0:16225146 --property env=DEV anypointproject3 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeployMuleApplication/49/target/banking-account-summary-mdm-api-v1.0.zip
Updating anypointproject3 ...
Domain                          anypointproject3.us-e1.cloudhub.io
Status                          UNDEPLOYED
Updated                         a few seconds ago
Runtime                         3.9.1
Previous runtime                3.9.2
File name                       banking-account-summary-mdm-api-v1.0.zip
Region                          us-east-1
Persistent queues               false
Persistent queues encrypted     false
Static IPs enabled              false
Monitoring                      Enabled. Will auto restart when not responding
Workers                         0.1 vCores * 1
Properties                      api."name =
```

the same thing when i try with jenkins script like this

```
 stage ('DeployeZipFileInCloudHub'){
           steps{
                script{ 
                def details=props;
                def buildNumber=env.BUILD_NUMBER;
                def files = findFiles(glob: "**/${buildNumber}/**/*.zip")
                def zipfilePath=env.WORKSPACE+"/"+files[0].path;                
            sh("""anypoint-cli --username=${details.username} --password=${details.password} --organization=${details.organizationName} runtime-mgr cloudhub-application modify --runtime 3.9.1 --workers 1 --workerSize 0.1 --region us-east-1 --property api.name\\=${APIName} --property api.version\\=${APIVersion} --property env\\=DEV ${details.runtimeapplicationName} ${zipfilePath}""")          
            }
            
       }
```

it could not able to identify anypoint cli and returning this ::

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeployMuleApplication@tmp/durable-98966186/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeployMuleApplication@tmp/durable-98966186/script.sh: anypoint-cli: not found
```

shell script works fine with all other commands ...
all my path variables looks good , could not able to identify why is not identifying anypoint-cli as a command,do i need to do any configuration or change in shell script ?.... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like anypoint-cli is not installed in the path of the user used to execute Jenkins. Install into that user account or if installed in a global directory use the full path.

Comment: The problem is when we install anypoint-cli with npm ,there is not binary package downloaded nor it has any file like "anypoint-cli.sh " , it is node.js which hanldes that command , so how can we say that anypoint-cli is installed in particular directry ..

Comment: If you can execute it has to be installed somewhere. For example in my system it is a link to a Javascript script: `/usr/local/bin/anypoint-cli -> ../lib/node_modules/anypoint-cli/src/app.js`
Use the `which` command to find its path: `$ which anypoint-cli` output `/usr/local/bin/anypoint-cli`

Comment: Thank u ..i have found the path by which and appended the path before command  /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.4.0/lib/node_modules/anypoint-cli/src/app.js:8 , now it is able to detect the anypoint-cli , but showing some version error  `Minimum required node version is ${version}, current node

Comment: Maybe it is finding an incorrect version of node in the path for that user?